# Is it considered proper (normal) to post the same question on askubuntu and at the same time on Unix&Linux?

Tags: discussion

Some questions that are fit to ask on http://unix.stackexchange.com are not fit here, but the other way around should always be ok. But is it? - (from askubuntu's point of view, of course)

Comment: Related MSO Q: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/195914) says NO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer on [the other question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1480/cross-posting-questions-that-are-on-topic-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites) may sound favourable but it is really talking about the wider community (outside of Stack Exchange). There is one reason why the answer to your question is a decided **no**:

#### Unix&Linux.SE does not allow cross posting.

It doesn't matter what *we* say, posting something to both here and there will break their rules so please avoid doing it.

Comment: meanwhile i already posted *this* question on their meta site :)

Comment: @cipricus That should be fine, since that question *is not the same as this one*: even if they are worded the same, this question is about whether or not something is considered proper on Ask Ubuntu and by its community; that question is about whether or not something is considered proper on Unix.SE and by its community.